# how to sum the column of a 2 dimentional array

Tags: c++

**it works at the beggining, adds 16 and 4 but then it doesn't add 2 + 3 and somehow even gets 8.

what am I doing wrong?**

I don't really understand how to count it separately

````
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;



int main() {
   int a = 0;
   int my_vector[][2] = { {16,2}, {4, 3} };


   for (int r = 0; r < 2; r++) 
   {
       for (int c = 0; c < 2; c++) 
       {
           std::cout << "  " << my_vector[r][c] << "\t";

           a = *my_vector[r] + *my_vector[c];
           
     }



       std::cout << "\n" << a;
       std::cout << "\n";
   }  ```
   


 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbTcO.png
````

Comment: you access elements for printing via `my_vector[r][c]` why do you use something else when adding them up?

Comment: You only add to `a` so you want the total sum of all elements in the 2D vector and the result should be 25, right?

Answer (score 1):

Here you dereference the first element in `my_vector` row `r` and add that to the dereferenced first element in `my_vactor` row `c`:

```
a = *my_vector[r] + *my_vector[c];
```

Then the result stored in `a` is overwritten in the next loop.

You probably meant:

```
a += my_vector[r][c]; // or: a = a + my_vector[r][c];
```

Another approach could be to use `std::for_each` and `std::accumulate`:

```
#include <algorithm> // std::for_each
#include <numeric>   // std::accumulate
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>  // std::begin, std::end

int main() {
    int a = 0;
    int my_vector[][2] = { {16,2}, {4, 3} };

    // for_each loops over the rows
    std::for_each(std::begin(my_vector), std::end(my_vector), [&a](auto& row) {
        // and accumulate sums up everything in columns in that row
        a += std::accumulate(std::begin(row), std::end(row), 0);
    });

    std::cout << "\n" << a  << '\n';
}
```